# scraping fundamentals - scraping a value that can either be a number or letters from a loosely formatted table

Tags: r, rvest

I'm failing at scraping a single value from a web page -- in particular the value below toward the bottom of the excerpted table corresponding to Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche (cfs)) -- the `NR` -- (for not reported) that is also sometimes a numeric value (ie one day it could be `NR`, another day it could be, say `123.4`.

My intended output is whatever the value is.

Here's the source  - http://www.spk-wc.usace.army.mil/fcgi-bin/midnight.py?days=0&report=SC7 (excerpt below is from about the middle of the page)

```
Camanche:
 Salt Springs:   Storage (acft) ....................     -NR
                 Precipitation (in) ................     -NR
                 Temperature (F) ...................     -NR
 Pardee:   Storage (acft) ..........................     -NR
           Inflow (sfd) ............................     -NR
           Precipitation (in) ......................     -NR
 Lower Bear Storage (acft) .........................     -NR
 Tiger Creek Precipitation (in) ....................     -NR
 Caples Lake:   Snow (Water Content Inches) ........     -NR
                Precipitation (in) .................     -NR
                Temperature (F) ....................     -NR
 Calaveras Big Trees:   Precipitation (in) .........     -NR
                        Temperature (F) ............     -NR
 Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche (cfs). ....     -NR
New Melones:
 Donnels:   Storage (acft) .........................   54179
```

I thought I could do something along the lines of:

```
library(rvest)
page <- "http://www.spk-wc.usace.army.mil/fcgi-bin/midnight.py?days=0&report=SC7"
text <- html_text(html_node(read_html(page),".h2 , pre")) #.h2 & pre Id'd by SelectorGadget
head(text)
#[1] ... -NR\n     Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche (cfs). ....     -NR\n New Melones:\n     Donnels:

#identifying bounds and using (.*?) for the part in between I want:

scrape_between <- "Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche (cfs). .... (.*?) \n New Melones"
value <- regmatches(text,regexec(scrape_between, text))
value
#[[1]]
#character(0)
```

But I'm not having much luck. I'm not sure if the preceding `. ....` is consistently that, but it seems it would at least be `...` . I wonder if there's a better way to leverage line numbers and the (loose) column format of the table? Any tips? Thank you much.

Comment: Is this string _Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche (cfs)_ always present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If will be helpful to perform an `str_split` on `\n`. You get the following,

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
page <- "http://www.spk-wc.usace.army.mil/fcgi-bin/midnight.py?days=0&report=SC7"
text <- html_text(html_node(read_html(page),".h2 , pre")) #.h2 & pre Id'd by SelectorGadget

text <- unlist(strsplit(text,"\n"))
scrape_between <- "Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche \\(cfs\\)" #Escape the parenthesis in regex
row <- text[str_detect(text,scrape_between)] #Get the row which contains the above text

extract_value <- gsub("^.*\\.(.*)$","\\1",row)# Get the value after the last elipses
clean_value <- gsub(" ","",extract_value) # Remove the extra spaces
```

You can use the same `text` variable which is a vector to read the first part of each line as a "label" and the second part as a "value". This is then be stored as a data frame for easier manipulation. The code above only isolated one particular line which contains "Mokelumne River..."

Answer (score 1):

If that string is constant you could try regex. `data` is the group of interest extracted.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

p <- read_html('http://www.spk-wc.usace.army.mil/fcgi-bin/midnight.py?days=0&report=SC7') %>% html_text()
data <- str_match_all(p,'Mokelumne River Natural Flow @ Camanche \\(cfs\\)[\\.\\s]+(.*)')[[1]][,2]
print(data)
```

---

Regex:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @QHarr for your solution - it also worked - and for the extra Regex info.